# Implicit call of constructor from operator==

Tags: c++, operators, implicit-conversion, implicit

I have the following code:

```
class Employee {
friend string FindAddr( list<Employee> lst,string name );
public:
Employee(const string& s){ cout << "Employee CTOR" << endl;}
bool operator==( Employee& e) {
    return e.name == name;
}
private:
string name;
string addr;
};


string FindAddr( list<Employee> lst, string name ) { 
string result = "";
for( list<Employee>::iterator itr = lst.begin(); itr != lst.end(); itr++ ) { 
    if ( *itr == name ) { // Problematic code
        return (*itr).addr;
    }
}
return result;
}
```

As I understand, the problematic line `if ( *itr == name )` should follow these steps:

1. Recognizing it is `operator==` on class `Employee`.
2. Trying to figure out if there is a conversion from `string name` to `Employee` so that the operator could work.
3. Implicitly call the constructor  `Employee(const string& s)` on object `string name`.
4. Continue with `operator==`.

However, this line gives me trouble at compile time:

```
Invalid operands to binary expression ('Employee' and 'string' (aka 'basic_string<char>'))
```

Even if I explicitly call the constructor:

`if ( *itr == Employee::Employee(name) )`

I get the same error.

This is confusing. I'm having trouble to understand when implicit constructor call works (and why the code doesn't work even if I explicitly call the constructor).

Thanks!

Comment: This is exactly why you should be using a `const` reference in `operator==`.

Comment: Hint: temporaries can not be bound to non-const references.

Comment: Since it isn't changing state, the member function should be `const` as well, so that it can be called on `const` objects.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The rule is:
**Temporaries can be bound only to a `const` reference.**

As you mentioned for the `==` to work,
The object `name` which is of the type `std::string` needs to be converted to type `Employee`, the conversion operators in your class `Employee` should make this happen. However, the created `Employee` object is an temporary object.i.e a nameless object which doesn't live long enough to need a name.Such a nameless temporary object cannot be bound to a non-const reference.<sup>[Ref 1]</sup>
So what you need is a const reference:

```
bool operator==(const Employee& e)
                ^^^^^^
```

---

<sup>[Ref 1]</sup>
**Motivation for the rule:**
Motivation for this particular rule is outline by Bajrne in Section 3.7 of *The design and evolution of C++.*

> I made one serious mistake, though, by allowing a non-constant reference to be initialized by an an non l-value. For example:

```
void incr(int &rr) {r++;}    

void g()
{
    double ss = 1;
    incr(ss);    //note: double passed int expected
}
```

> Because of the difference in the type the `int&` cannot refer to the `double` passed so a temporary was generated to hold an int initialized by `ss`'s value. Thus the `incr()` modified the temporary, and the result wasn't reflected back to the function.

Thus many a times temporary objects are generated unknowingly in function calls, where they are least expected and one might (wrongly)assume that their function works on the original object being passed, whereas the function operates on the temporary.Thus it's easy to write a code that assumes one thing and does another.So to avoid such easy to mislead situations the rule was put in place.

Comment: Declaring the function `const` would also be a good idea. Or better still, make it a non-member to allow conversions on both arguments (i.e. to allow `name == *itr` as well as `*itr == name`).

Comment: Temporaries surely take a space in memory and have an address... (for all but but those that fit in a register). Also the explanation of why they cannot be bound to a non-const reference is... *misleading* to say the least. I.e. it is more of a personal opinion than anything else --the exact same issues crop up with a `const` reference, for example, and some compilers have extensions to support this... *security* is not a reason for a language feature (*safety* might be)...

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas In fact, the reason why you cannot initialize a non-const reference with a temporary has been documented by the person who made the decision (Stroustrup): it turned out to be too error prone.  Not due to the lifetime, but due to the fact that you sometimes got temporaries without realizing it, and modified them, when you meant to modify the initializing object.

Comment: @James: I knew (I remember reading on that lines in *The design and evolution of C++*), I just don't like when people *second-guess* the reasons and create *urban myths* :)

Comment: With regards to the const reference, the preferred way of writing this in modern C++ is `Employee const& e`.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: Constructive criticism is welcome.I modified the answer to be more accurate.Some people do take the efforts to correct mistakes if they are pointed out.

Comment: @JamesKanze: Your explanation was correct.I modified the answer with precise details.

Answer (score 0):

`*itr` gives you an `Employee`, so you're comparing an `Employee` to a string, `name`.

What you need is `if ( *itr.name == name )`

That way you'd be comparing the `Employee` in the list's name to the name you're searching for.

Comment: This works (with a getter at least), but it doesn't solve the underlying problem. `*itr == name` should work.

Comment: I agree, this isn't the solution I was looking for.